# How to show multiple images in jQuery Drag & Drop Image Uploader plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am using jQuery Drag & Drop Image Uploader plugin https://www.codehim.com/demo/jquery-image-uploader-preview-and-delete/#example-2 and i want to show all images inside drop box plugin from db but I have no idea how can i show that please help me thank.

code :
return $data['editRooms'];

result :

```
https://ibb.co/R2Q9s75
```

[image]

**RoomController**

```
 public function edit($roomId)
    {   $data=[

           'editRooms' => Room::with('roomDetail')->where('id',$roomId)->first(),
        ];
        return view('cms.edit-room',$data);
    }
```

**html view**

```
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <label class="active">Images Upload</label>
                    <div class="input-images" style="padding-top: 
                     .5rem;" ></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript Source**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
   //     let preloaded = [
    //     {id: 1, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=1'},
    //     {id: 2, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=2'},
    //     {id: 3, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=3'},
    // ];
    $('.input-images').imageUploader({
        preloaded: preloaded,
        imagesInputName: 'photos',
        preloadedInputName: 'old'
    });
    });
```